# Conditional statements not being picked up

Tags: html, conditional-comments

I've read around about using conditional statements but never successfully got them to work! This is what I have:

```
<!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="First name" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 6)]-->
    <input type="text" value="First name" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I want it to display the first input for every other browser except IE and the second statement to display for IE6 or greater.

At the moment when testing it initially in Chrome it's just showing them both!

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were prematurely closing your second `if` (and subsequently unnecessarily reopening your second `endif`), which is causing all browsers to see your second `input`. It also needs to be `gte IE 6` if you want to include IE6:

```
<!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="First name" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 6)]>
    <input type="text" value="First name" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: If memory serves, assuming you have no content between your first `endif` and your second `if` it looks like you can remove some extra dashes as well `<!--<![endif]><![if (gte IE 6)]>` since you're merely writing HTML comments as far as other browsers are concerned. But I suggest sticking with the code given in my answer to make it easier to understand and reuse.

Comment: All these years of avoiding conditionals and it's finally working. Literally thanks a million!!